# VS 2010: Can’t insert mvvm-light snippet using shortcut - incompatibility with resharper 5?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, mvvm-light

i recently installed some snippets that come with the mvvm-light framework i am using. And sure enought i checked via

```
    Tools > Code Snippet Manager
```

and they are installed under "My Code Snippets".

If i do insert Snipper (right click in code window) or CTRL K + CTRL X then i can search within all available snippets....

But i do believe its possible to just type the shortcut key (in this case it is mvvmlocatorproperty) and pressing tab inserts the snippet

BUT when i type the shortcut key it is not recognizing anything...

What am i doing wrong??

This is not an incompatibility with resharper 5? - which i have installed

Any ideas really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior if you have ReSharper IntelliSense turned on - ReSharper suppressed VS native IntelliSense in all file types that it supports, and ReSharper IntelliSense doesn't show VS code snippets.
Basically you have a choice of two alternative ways to go:

1. Turn off ReSharper IntelliSense completely and use VS native IntelliSense. To do that, go to ReSharper > Options > Environment > IntelliSense > General and check "Visual Studio". This will revert back to VS IntelliSense that shows snippets in its completion lists.
2. Implement your snippet as a [ReSharper live template](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Creating_and_Editing_Templates__Creating_a_Template.html). This will allow you to both have your templates listed in completion lists, and enjoy all advantages that ReSharper IntelliSense provides including support for lowerCamelHumps (completing MyLongTypeName by typing mltn), variable naming suggestions, different rendering styles for immediate and inherited members in completion lists, generating trivial code, etc. You can learn more about ReSharper code completion from [this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion.html), and its child pages.

Answer (score 1):

No it should work with R# 5.0, I have it installed also. I am not sure what the issue is. Send me an email and I will pass you my MSN ID so that we can try and debug that.

Thanks,
Laurent

Comment: I sent you an email with regards to this.. Best regards

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem? I have the same VS setup with R# 5.1 and snippet doesn't appear either.