# MVC Snippets for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

In 2013 Express for Web there were MVC code snippets for adding default actions and post actions (`mvcaction4` and `mvcpostaction4`). Visual Studio 2015 Community doesn't appear to have these. Is there a particular tool or download I need to install to restore these or get the MVC5 versions? Or do I need to copy them and stick them in my custom scriptlets?

Comment: Have you tried to create a snippet [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) way?

Comment: I am aware of the old way, just don't know if something is missing from my installation or if I'm missing some addon. I can do it manually as a last resort

Comment: Have you found any MVC snippets? :( I'm missing those too, and cannot believe no one have created any yet.

Comment: I also had the problem but it turned out to be Resharper. See [Using VS Code Snippets with Resharper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820446/using-vs-code-snippets-with-resharper).

Comment: you can create your own snippets by installing code snippet extension in VS.

Answer (score 0):

for `mvc4action` I have created the snippet for VS 2017 , you will need to create file with '*.snippet' extension , save file then go to **Tools** menu in VS 2017 ,select **Code Snippets Manager** and import the file you created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<CodeSnippets  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">  
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">  
        <Header>  
            <Title>mvcaction</Title> 
            <Shortcut>mvc4action</Shortcut>             
        </Header>  
        <Snippet>  
            <Code Language="csharp">  
                <![CDATA[public ActionResult $ActionName$()
                {
                    return View();$end$
                }
          ]]>  
            </Code> 
<Declarations>  
    <Literal>  
        <ID>ActionName</ID>  
        <ToolTip>Replace ActionName.</ToolTip>  
        <Default>Action</Default>  
    </Literal>  
</Declarations>         
        </Snippet>  
    </CodeSnippet>  



</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to search bar at the top of the Visual Studio window ---> type MVC 4 ---> you'll get the option to download and install the support for MVC --->download and install and then the snippets will work.