# How to show all Visual Studio's code snippets in Resharper's IntelliSense?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Resharper's IntelliSense only shows its own Live Templates but not Visual Studio's code snippets.

Is there a way to make Resharper IntelliSense to show all VS code snippets?

In Templates Explorer of Resharper I found that it has many Live Snippets marked as `Imported Visual C# Snippets`

[image]

But it didn't import all of them, only some of them. For example, Resharper didn't import `propfull` code snippet from Visual Studio(as you can see on the first screenshot `propfull` isn't on the list):
[image]

I can't find a feature in Resharper to import VS code snippets manually, one by one, or all of them together. I tried `Import...` button in Live Templates Manager in Resharper but apparently it only allows to import Live Templates(.DotSettings and .XML files, not .snippets files), but not Code Snippets files. Is it possible to import VS code snippets somehow?

All I want is to somehow make all VS code snippets work in Resharper IntelliSense. Maybe there's some third party tool that allows to convert snippets into Live Templates or something? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, this is coming from the Support of R# -> https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206667595-Intellisense-with-Code-Snippets?page=1#community_comment_206450199

And this is a workaround -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820446/using-vs-code-snippets-with-resharper 

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I saw these threads from 2010. I just thought that in 10 years they or community managed to fix it and show  all VS snippets in Resharper IntelliSense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ReSharper does not import any VS templates on installation or on the first launch. All templates you see in Template Explorer were manually added to default settings of ReSharper - there is no a "Code Snippets to Live Template" converter https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-273779.

So, if you would like to get `propfull` template in Live Templates, you have to create it manually - open `ReSharper | Tools | Templates Explorer | Live Templates | C# | New Template` and put following code there:

```
private $TYPE$ _$Var$;

public $TYPE$ $Property$ 
{ 
    get { return _$Var$; } 
    set { _$Var$ = value; } 
}
```

and adjust `Var` placeholder: `Value -> Choose Macro -> "Value of another variable with the first characters in lower case" -> OK -> "another variable" -> Choose "Property"`. Also `Editable Occurrence -> Not editable`. Then change the order of placeholders for the new added template to be the following: 
- `Type` 
- `Property`
- `Var`

In this case, `Var` will inherit a correct name from Property.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion that is how i did
This picture shows the code. As Alexander did.
[image: Screenshot of code of property full template]

This picture the configuration needed in Resharper Template editor
in Visual Studio
[image: Screenshot of configuration]

Another way to insert templates are the Mnemonic package extension of Resharper. That package has a lot of live templates for C#.
See extension [image: Live Template Extension Package]